# Alignment of lightning-datatable headers

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I'm attempting to right-align the contents and header values of a lightning-datatable in an LWC. I can get the content to align correctly by adding cell-attributes but the column header remains left-aligned, does anyone know how to correct this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set CSS for datatable headers due to [LWC's Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), which ensures both CSS and Element isolation.

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child

Usually SLDS allows to override some properties via [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#Styling-Hooks-What-Are-Styling-Hooks), but not in that case.

Starting from the [Data Tables blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/) you could create your own component and have full control over its style.